# Office 365 REST API with Basic Authorization

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi, office365api, office365-restapi

I am trying to get both personal calendar and shared calendar in an office 365 account using RESTapi. Since currently Oauth2 doesn't support accessing shared calendar, I'm testing my code with basic authorization.

I have three calendars in my account:

1. user1@domain.com(own calendar)
2. user2@domain.com(shared calendar)
3. user3@domain.com(shared calendar)

Using following end points I was able to get events using basic authorization:

https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Users('user1@domain.com')/Events

The strange part is for the past two days I'm not able to get events for user1@domain.com and user2@domain.com using the same end point. I get the following error when I try to access the events:

{"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/$metadata#Users('user1@domain.com')/Events","value":[{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerError","message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}}

But I can still access events for user3@domain.com using same endpoint and basic authentication.

I also tried to access own calendar using oauth2. I get similar error

{"value":[{"error":{"code":"ErrorInternalServerError","message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}}

But I can successfully talk to calendar endpoint

I was wondering if anyone had seen this error before. Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using Basic authentication isn't recommended, and isn't supported for production use. Basic is there for now to ease exploration of the API, but will be deactivated at some point in the future.

With that being said, you said that you get the error when you access your own calendar using OAuth2, is that right? This sounds like it might be an intermittent issue, but there's not really enough information to know exactly what's happening. If you're still seeing it, it would be good to [add instrumentation headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn720380(v=exchg.150).aspx) to your requests (`User-Agent`, `client-request-id`, `return-client-request-id`) and get a network trace of the request response.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for your response. I will try adding more headers to check the request response. I was using basic authentication to only test my code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jason's comments, please use our production endpoint https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0 instead of our old preview endpoint https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/  See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/09/02/deprecating-the-rest-api-preview-endpoint.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi Venkat,Thanks for your response. I will change it to production url. I have one other question - do you know when accessing shared calendars is supported using Oauth2? I couldn't find information any where about this.

Comment: Not yet.  We are still working on adding support but no ETA yet.

Answer (score 0):

This confused me too. Everything on the web will point you to using the Office 365 API, but trust me, that's not what you will want to do. You will want to use the Exchange API. Office 365 just IS an Exchange server so you can automate it in the same way you can automate any Exchange server. There is sample code here. It is very simple.

[Consume Office 365 REST API Without UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242526/consume-office-365-rest-api-without-ui/39262312#39262312)

The Office 365 API is just a set of tools for buildings UI based apps that allow the user to enter their Office 365 credentials and allow the app to work on their behalf.